# Proving that $-(2n+1/n+1) \leq 0$ for all n a natural number.

Tags: inequality

I was just wondering if someone can help me with a real basic proof.

Prove that $-\frac{2n+1}{n+1} \leq 0 \forall n \in \mathbb N$.

Is it just enough to show that $-\frac{2n+1}{n+1} > 0$ cannot happen? 
When I was talking with my professor, he said that we didn't have to use induction to prove it, so that's why I came up with the above instead, to show a contradiction.

Comment: No proof by induction $\implies$ Proof by contradiction? What about *direct* proofs?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just notice that $\frac{2n+1}{n+1}>0$ for every natural $n$, as we are dividing two positive numbers. It immediately follows that $-\frac{2n+1}{n+1}<0$.

Answer (score 1):

$n$ is natural, so, $n>0  \implies 1+n > 1 \implies 1/(n+1) < 1 \implies 1/(n+1) <2  \implies -2 + 1/(n+1) < 0 \implies -(2n+1)/(n+1) <0$

Comment: [This tutorial](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference) might help you in the future.